# "This application is available to over 0 devices."

Tags: android, google-play

I continue to get this as I'm uploading my Android app information, screen shots, and other information:

> This application is available to over 0 devices.

Right before that it shows:

> Screen layouts: NORMAL LARGE XLARGE
>   Required device features
>   android.hardware.touchscreen
>   android.hardware.screen.portrait

What is causing this?

Comment: Please add your AndroidManifest, it's way easier to answer that based on it's content. Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have you activated the Android [application package file (APK)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29)?

There is *compatibility* and there is *availability*. 
Your error message specifically refers to ***availability***.

In order to make your application available, you first have to activate it. 
You can do that in Advanced Mode by highlighting your package and clicking Activate.

Answer (score 12):

Switch to APK files tab. In Advanced Mode click on Activate next to you APK file. This worked for me.