# Android Device Compatibilities

Tags: android, submit

I've written a simple app that only uses swipe gestures for Android but when I uploaded it to the Play store it says it will only be available to 0 devices.

Here is the compatibility report from Play Submission page

```
This application is only available to devices with these features, as defined in your application manifest.
Screen layouts: SMALL NORMAL LARGE XLARGE
Required device features
android.hardware.touchscreen
This application is available to over 0 devices.
```

Comment: Your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236071/this-application-is-available-to-over-0-devices.  Take a look at Nikhil's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved via linked answer. For simplicity, all you have to do is switch to APK tab and then "Activate" the APK file.